SSSD access filter parsing issues
I'm trying to set up a filter for SSSD to permit only members of a certain group access. This should work with the following two lines inside sssd.conf:
access_provider = ad
ad_access_filter = <LDAP QUERY>

(Yes, I know I could also use the simple provider, but I'm trying to learn a thing or two...)
Here's the SSSD logs after an attempted sign in that seem to be relevant:
   *  (2024-08-15 14:39:07): [be[my.domain]] [parse_filter] (0x0020): [RID#8] Keyword in filter [(&(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=Docker Admins,OU=Custom Resource Access Groups,DC=MY,DC=DOMAIN)(objectClass=user))] did not match expected format
********************** BACKTRACE DUMP ENDS HERE *********************************

(2024-08-15 14:39:07): [be[my.domain]] [ad_sdap_access_done] (0x0040): [RID#8] Error retrieving access check result: Host Access Denied
********************** PREVIOUS MESSAGE WAS TRIGGERED BY THE FOLLOWING BACKTRACE:
   *  (2024-08-15 14:39:07): [be[my.domain]] [ad_parse_access_filter] (0x0080): [RID#8] Access filter [(&(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=Docker Admins,OU=Custom Resource Access Groups,DC=MY,DC=DOMAIN)(objectClass=user))] could not be parsed, skipping

At a glance it seems SSSD is having trouble... parsing the query? Except I know my query works because I've tested it in DC directly, and got the results I wanted. So why is SSSD complaining about parsing it? Could it be because the group / OUs contain spaces in the names? I've tried putting " around the query in sssd.conf but that didn't really help either.
Any idea why SSSD might be having issues?

Found the cause. From various online articles it seemed that SSSD would parse the query as is, but it turns out it's getting confused by the : in the query.
The solution was to prefix the query with DOM:my.domain:, so
DOM:my.domain:(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=Docker Admins,OU=Custom Resource Access Groups,DC=MY,DC=DOMAIN)

I also got rid of the user-filter because it was redundant.
